# Unable to receive stats while using aggregate in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working with mongoDB and postman. I'm new to mongoDB-aggregate. Can someone help me out with it. [This is my mongo code. (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vinCt.png) and [This is postman snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWhwE.png).
I'm not sure why I'm not getting any output in 'stats' section.

My database of this type :

```
"ratingsAverage": 4.4,
"ratingsQuantity": 7,
"_id": "5c88fa8cf4afda39709c296c",
"name": "The Wine Taster",
"duration": 5,
"maxGroupSize": 8,
"difficulty": "easy",
"price": 1997,
"summary": "Exquisite wines, scenic views, exclusive barrel tastings,  and much more",
```

Comment: Please paste code rather than uploading images

Comment: Your `$match` stage is wrong. The operator is `$gte` not `gte`.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor,  i messed up with $gte, thanks that helped me out. Will be  sure of  pasting code next time :)

Comment: Welcome. You should not post code or anything else that is represented in textual form. Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more information.